# Azure Form Recognizer pricing

Tags: azure, api

"I've got some questions about the Azure Form Recognizer pricing.  The website says $50 per 1000 pages for the S0 Web custom document type. If I upload a 1000 page PDF but make 10 API calls on each page, will we be charged per API call to the uploaded document or based purely on the number of pages?  So would we expect a $50 bill or a $500 bill for those 1000 pages?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had this same doubt and drilled down a bit more to figure out that it is based on the number of pages you analyze using the API. So in your case, since, you are calling the API which is essentially analyzing the pages of the document, the bill would be $500.
However, it is always better to save the results and refer them later as with one model the result will always be the same for the same document/page.